# Strong acid definition

Tags: acid-base

Strong acids are defined as being stronger than $\ce{H3O+}$ and thus dissociate completely in water. However, what does it mean exactly to be stronger than $\ce{H3O+}$? Is it the Ka value? Also, what makes $\ce{H3O+}$  the strongest acid in water that can exist in aqueous form? Does it have to do with water's ability as a proton receiver?

Comment: Yes, Ka value. It's not true that hydronium cation is strongest present in aq. solution, though. It's just that stronger ones are present in lower concentrations, at least in diluted solutions.

Comment: Water. That's what makes H3O+ the strongest acid that can exist in water.

Comment: It's called the [solvent levelling effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leveling_effect)

Comment: @Mithoron, could you please elaborate on your comment?

Comment: Everything is equilibrium. If an acid is just marginally stronger than H3O+ there will still be a measurable amount of undissociated acid except in very dilute solution. Think about how the equilibrium constant is defined. Nature doesn't possess an on/off switch, its more like a potentiometer.